# Load PHP Script Outside of Zend Framework Before Bootstrapping

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I need to run a php script once before my zend framework application is bootstrapped and run. This works now by calling this initial script in my /public/index.php, however the script is run for all subsequent zend framework page requests as well. I need this script to only be run once on the initial request and not again when additional pages are loaded via ajax.

My initial attempts were to set some php constants in the /public/index.php file like so:

if (!defined('SOME_VAR')) require_once 'path/to/script/to/run/once.php';
define('SOME_VAR', '1);

However, when another page is loaded via ajax, even though I've defined 'SOME_VAR', it doesn't persist and stay as defined and the script is executed again.

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11, Apache (Xampp).

Executing this script AFTER Zend has been bootstrapped and run (inside Zend Framework) is not an option.

Comment: Someone please tell him about Contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants don't work because they only exist for the duration of the request.

It sounds like you want to figure out if the current request is a regular request or an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) request.

You could try something like this at the top of your index.php:

```
<?php
define('IS_AJAX_REQUEST', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');

if (! IS_AJAX_REQUEST){
    // run your code.
}
```

If you're using sessions, you could also just set a flag in the session once you special code has been run, and test for that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of constants. What if the request wasn't Ajax and my issue still existed? There should be some "Zend like" way to fire off an external script, to set some front end html only once, and then continue doing the things that zend does.

Comment: @whitespy: If the point of the external script is to render some html into the output, then it doesn't sound like it really needs to happen before bootstrap. In that case, making changes in the layout view script - either by front-controller plugin, action helper, or simply in layout view script itself - could suffice. Or is there some other reason that the external processing needs to occur before bootstrap?

Comment: @DavidWeinraub: There are a lot of other things the script does (authentication, render links, etc), but the over all outcome is to display some dynamic html. I know that this would be better after the bootstrap, but I'm trying avoid that right now. Recreating this script inside zf w/ layouts/action helpers would be far more work than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Zend Framework Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.examples.html):

However, should custom initialization be necessary, you have two choices. First, you can write methods prefixed with _init to specify discrete code to bootstrap. These methods will be called by bootstrap(), and can also be called as if they were public methods: bootstrap(). They should accept an optional array of options.
If your resource method returns a value, it will be stored in a container in the bootstrap. This can be useful when different resources need to interact (such as one resource injecting itself into another). The method getResource() can then be used to retrieve those values.

The other option is to use resource plugins. Resource plugins are objects that perform specific initializations, and may be specified:

- When instantiating the Zend_Application object
- During initialization of the bootstrap object
- By explicitly enabling them via method calls to the bootstrap object

Resource plugins implement Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract, which defines simply that they allow injection of the caller and options, and that they have an init() method.